# Python csv.dictreader does not appear to be reading all rows of csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a program that, in short, creates a CSV file and compares it line by line to a previously generated CSV file (created on previous script execution), and logs differences between the two.

I'm having a weird issue where csv.dictreader does not appear to be reading all rows of the NEW log - but it DOES read all rows of the OLD log. What makes this issue even more puzzling is that if I run the program again, it creates a new log, and will now read the previous log all the way to the end.

Here's what I mean if that made no sense:

1. Run program to generate LOG A
2. Run program again to generate LOG B
3. csv.dictreader does not read all the way through LOG B, but it DOES read all the way through LOG A
4. Run program again to generate LOG C
5. csv.dictreader does NOT read all the way through LOG C, but it DOES read all the way through LOG B (which it previously didn't although no information in the csv file has changed)

Here's the relevant function:

```
def compare_data(newLog, oldLog):
    # this function compares the new scan Log to the old Log to determine if, and how much, memory space has changed
    # within each directory
    # both arguments should be filenames of the logs

    # use the .csv library to create dictionary objects out of files and read thru them
    newReader = csv.DictReader(newLog)
    oldReader = csv.DictReader(oldLog)

    oldDirs, newDirs = [], []

    # write data from new log into dictionary list
    for row in newReader:
        newLogData = {}

        newLogData['ScanDate'] = row['ScanDate']
        newLogData['Directory'] = row['Directory']
        newLogData['Size'] = int(row['Size'])

        newDirs.append(newLogData)

    # write data from old log into another dictionary list
    for row in oldReader:
        oldLogData = {}

        oldLogData['ScanDate'] = row['ScanDate']
        oldLogData['Directory'] = row['Directory']
        oldLogData['Size'] = int(row['Size'])

        oldDirs.append(oldLogData)

    # now compare data between the two dict lists to determine what's changed


    for newDir in newDirs:
        for oldDir in oldDirs:
            dirMatch = False

            if newDir['Directory'] == oldDir['Directory']:
                # we have linked dirs. now check to see if their size has changed
                dirMatch = True

                if newDir['Size'] != oldDir['Size']:
                    
                    print(newDir['Directory'], 'has changed in size! It used to be', oldDir['Size'],
                          'bytes, now it\'s', newDir['Size'], 'bytes! Hype')

    # now that we have determined changes, now we should check for unique dirs
    # unique meaning either a dir that has been deleted since last scan, or a new dir added since last scan

    find_unique_dirs(oldDirs, newDirs)
```

Based on the fact that the old log gets read in its entirety, I don't think it would be an issue of open quotes in filenames or anything like that.

Comment: What makes you think it's not reading all the way through? What are `len(oldDirs)` and `len(newDirs)`?

Comment: Did you close or flush the new log file before calling the function?

Comment: You *really* must provide a [mcve]. I high suspect that the issue lies in whatever you are passing in to the file. File objects are stateful iterators. It sounds like you may have advanced the latest log file before it is passed to this function.

Comment: @Barmar len(oldDirs) is 423 and len(newDirs) is 379. They should both be 423. And when I open up the CSV file and manually inspect it, 423 is the correct number every time. I also just added close() commands for both logs at the end of compare_data and that didn't change my results

Comment: The `close()` needs to be done BEFORE you call `compare_data()`. My suspicion is that the last part of the file is still buffered in memory.